# Most efficient way to migrate a website with page builder content to another host with a different page builder

Tags: wordpress

The internet host I'm using for a large website is shutting down so I need to move the website over a new host. I built the website using a page builder which was provided by the host and is not longer available to use. I'm not sure if I'll have to rebuild the website from the ground up or if there's a method to move the website and all of the components I've made using the page builder to a new host.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately if you are switching page builders you need to redo the entire work.

Comment: Yes you will have to start over.